# Selenium chromdriver saving files with .crdownload extension

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Using the following selenium/chrome preferences, I can download a file to the same folder that I run the original python file from, and it works properly (file saves as `download.xls`)

```
DOWNLOAD_DIR = r'/mnt/ssd/rl-scrape/files/dev/dl/'
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "download.default.directory": DOWNLOAD_DIR,
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "safebrowsing.enabled": True})
```

I understand that I've typo'd `download.default_directory` above. If I correct it, the file gets downloaded to the desired directory, but as `download.xls.crdownload` and not `download.xls`

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem. Have you found any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Chrome adds the `.crdownload` extension while the download is in progress.  Once the file is complete, it will rename the file to its proper name.  As long as you see `.crdownload`, the download is not complete.

Comment: I understand that - but regardless of if the .crdownload extension is there - the file is the same

Answer (score 2):

Add a time delay for the download process to finish before it quits the window. Worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).